# Azure Function execution ignoring 'exit' command

Tags: powershell, azure

I have a Azure Function (PowerShell) that contains some error handling.  In the event of an error I carry out a couple of simple actions and I then wish to stop exectution, however this is not working; PowerShell is ignoring the `exit 1` command and continuing execution.

```
try{
    $metrics = Get-AzureMetrics -BearerToken $bearer_token -SubscriptionId $env:HC_SubscriptionId -ResourceGroup $env:HC_ResourceGroup -ResourceType $env:HC_ResourceType -ResourceName $env:HC_ResourceName
} catch {
    $failure = $_.Exception.Message
    Write-Output "[ERROR] Failed to GET metrics from Azure Monitor. $failure"
    Invoke-LogToSplunk -EventHost "bvt-processevnts" -Source $env:HealthCheckFunctionName -Message "Failed to GET metrics from Azure Monitor. $failure" -Severity "ERROR" -SplunkUri $env:SplunkUrl -AccessToken $env:SplunkToken | Out-Null
    exit 1
}
```

Note that `exit 1` works when testing locally, it's only when I run it as an Azure Function that I see this issue.  I've also tried `Return` and `Break`, but those commands are ignored also.

I've considered replacing `exit 1` with `$error_occurred = $true` and then nesting proceeding commands in an `if` statement (see below).  However, I'd like to avoid this if possible as it's harder to manage in the long run, and less clear to others in the team who may need to view/edit the Azure Function in the future.

```
if ( ! ( $error_occurred ) ) {
    # Other commands
}
```

So my question is (hopefully) simple; how can I tell the Azure Function to stop execution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This solution may not fit your needs, but could you try something like this?

```
Function Get-AzureMetricsOrFail ($bearer_token) {
    try{
        $metrics = Get-AzureMetrics -BearerToken $bearer_token -SubscriptionId $env:HC_SubscriptionId -ResourceGroup $env:HC_ResourceGroup -ResourceType $env:HC_ResourceType -ResourceName $env:HC_ResourceName
    } catch {
        $failure = $_.Exception.Message
        Write-Output "[ERROR] Failed to GET metrics from Azure Monitor. $failure"
        Invoke-LogToSplunk -EventHost "bvt-processevnts" -Source $env:HealthCheckFunctionName -Message "Failed to GET metrics from Azure Monitor. $failure" -Severity "ERROR" -SplunkUri $env:SplunkUrl -AccessToken $env:SplunkToken | Out-Null
    }
    return $metrics
}

$metrics_result = Get-AzureMetricsOrFail -bearer_token 'some_token'

if($metrics_result) {
    'Successfully obtained Azure Metrics'
    # Rest of code
} else {
    'Failed getting Azure Metrics.'
}
```

Alternatively, maybe try just moving the Exit statement?

```
try{
    $metrics = Get-AzureMetrics -BearerToken $bearer_token -SubscriptionId $env:HC_SubscriptionId -ResourceGroup $env:HC_ResourceGroup -ResourceType $env:HC_ResourceType -ResourceName $env:HC_ResourceName
} catch {
    $failure = $_.Exception.Message
    Write-Output "[ERROR] Failed to GET metrics from Azure Monitor. $failure"
    Invoke-LogToSplunk -EventHost "bvt-processevnts" -Source $env:HealthCheckFunctionName -Message "Failed to GET metrics from Azure Monitor. $failure" -Severity "ERROR" -SplunkUri $env:SplunkUrl -AccessToken $env:SplunkToken | Out-Null
}
if(!($metrics)) {
    exit
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I'd considered something similar, and it would work.  However, I'd rather still be able to stop execution, so hoepfully there is an Azure Function compliant way of doing so, somewhere out there...

Comment: I modified my answer. I wonder if the Exit statement is not working because it is inside of the try, catch. Perhaps my second piece of code will work for you.

Comment: Good shout, that does indeed force the execution to stop.  The only problem now is even with `exit 1`, the Function App still returns a 200 and logs success.  I guess there I'll have to change my approach to get it to return a non-200...